# javascript function with instance variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function that has an instance variable for each assignment e.g.

```
function Sample() {
    Sample.myInstanceVar = true; // <--- This var should be instance-specific
}

var a = Sample;
console.log(a.myInstanceVar); // should return undefined and it does
a.apply(this);

var b = Sample;
console.log(b.myInstanceVar); // i would like to get this one to return undefined here, but it returns true;
```

Hopefully, you get the point :-)

UPDATE:>

I am not interested in Sample being an instance since its a function i am referencing. I want Sample to have some sort of variable or instance that is specific to the scope/context i am referencing Sample in.

Comment: You're _completely_ misunderstanding instances.   (you don't actually have any)

Comment: `var a = Sample;` is a reference to the `Sample()` function, not an instance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: i reference this sample function several places, i would like to know in which scope this has been run.

Comment: @Flexo: That's totally impossible.  Making a variable point to a function doesn't change the function.

Answer (score 9):

```
function Sample() {
    Sample.myInstanceVar = true; // <--- This var should be instance-specific
}
```

No. That modifies the global object referenced by `Sample`

```
 var a = Sample;
```

No. That copies the reference to the aforementioned global object.

---

*How to create an instance*:

```
var a = new Sample();
```

The `new` is the important bit. The `()` are optional if you have no arguments, but including them is good style.

*How to define a property on an instance*:

Use the `this` keyword. When used inside a function *that is called with `new`* it refers to the instance being created.

```
function Sample() {
    this.myInstanceVar = true;
}
```

Of course, this will run for *every* instance of `Sample` that you create, so `b` will have a different `true` stored in it.

Comment: This does not do the trick for me since Sample now is a type object instead of a type function.
I need Sample to be a function that has a variable that are scope/context specific

Comment: @Flexo Since you didn't provide any context for your question, it would be hard for anyone to provide an answer specific to your instance. The answer above addresses the question you asked.

Comment: It still does. You don't have an instance when addressing `Sample` like that, so you can't make anything specific to an instance if it doesn't exist in the first place